# ImportError on console but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the folowing dir structure

```
|population_model
--|__init__.py
--|run.py
```

inside `__init__.py` I have the following:

```
def my_func():
   ...
   return
```

on run.py I have

```
from population_model import my_func
```

When I run the project from inside `PyCharm`the code runs beautifully.
But when running from Terminal:
`my/path/to/population_model/python run.py`

I get `ImportError: No module named population_model`

What might be the cause?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same interpreter, with the same working directory?

Comment: Are you sure your PyCharm is running from the same execution root as where you are running it from your terminal?

Comment: using`print os.getcwd()` I got the same root. If there is a better way to check that?

Comment: About same interpeter - Not sure how to check that.

Comment: .... I'm confused. Where does `my_func` come from? Is it written directly in `__init__.py`? Or is it in another module within the `population_model` directory?

Comment: `my_func` is written in `__init__.py`.
I will clarify on original post.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely PyCharm's Run configuration is setting the Working Directory to your project, where it can find population_model. In the terminal, cd to the directory first.