# ImportError in the console, but import is working in PyCharm

Tags: python, import, pycharm, libraries

I have a programm which imports the request module like this:

```
import urllib
from urllib import request
...
```

The programm is running fine in the PyCharm-IDE.
But when I run the same code in the console in Linux Ubuntu I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name request
```

Is there a problem with my path? Should I provide more information to solve this problem?

According to [ImportError on console but not in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847526/importerror-on-console-but-not-in-pycharm) PyCharm is setting the working directory.

But when I add this working directory to my script like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/kame/Dropbox/myCode/python/scripts/')
```

I still get the same error.

Comment: Could be the case that PyCharm is adding some path to python path. Do `print('\n'.join(sys.path))` to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`urllib.request` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) is introduced in Python 3.x.

I suspect PyCharm is using Python 3.x, while in console you are using Python 2.x. Try using Python 3.x in console.